# Protected method call in Python?

Tags: python, exception, annotations

I have a sequence of calls that I need to make, all of which could throw an exception and I want a good way of protecting the calls.  I am trying to find a more professional way to do the following in python:

```
def protected_call(method):
   result = None
   try:
       result= method()
   except:  pass

   return result
class Test():


  def terminate(): 
     protected_call(self.could_throw_exception)
     protected_call(self.receiver.stop)
     protected_call(self.connection.stop)
     #etc
```

Is there a better way to do this   ? Maybe with an annotation ?

Just to clarify, I **dont** want to put  an annotation on the original method ie:

```
class Receiver():
  @protected
  def stop():
     print 'I dont want to do this'

class Test():
  @protected
  def could_throw_exception():
     print 'dont want this'
  def stop(): 
     self.could_throw_exception()
     self.receiver.stop()
```

This is what i want:

```
class Receiver():
  def stop():
     print 'I want this'

class Test():

  def could_throw_exception():
     print 'like this'

  '''This one cares about crashing'''
  def stop()
     self.could_throw_exception()
     self.receiver.stop()
     self.connection.stop()

  '''This one does not'''
  def terminate(): 
     #i want to define it at the call level.
     @protected
     self.could_throw_exception()
     @protected
     self.receiver.stop()
```

Comment: You want to ignore exceptions? That doesn't seem like a good idea. Look into [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and [finally](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Comment: Looks good to me, but, why would you want a test to ignore *every* exception?

Comment: In reality I am going to catch all communication/transport exceptions but for the exapmle i didn't want to complicate things.  This is part of a shutdown process so I am asking a thread to shutdown gracefuly... if the dont I dont care bc I am moving on.  I thought about passing in an exception list to the protected_call..

Comment: side remark: you can simplify your `protected_call()` function by removing the `result` variable, like so: `try: return method(); except: pass` (nothing else is needed, because functions return None by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nmichaels suggested, this kind of thing is best handled via the `with` statement.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def suppress_exceptions(*exceptions):
    if not exceptions:
        exceptions = Exception
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions:
        # You would log an error here
        # If you have logging in your application
        pass

with suppress_exceptions():
    1/0

print("Ignored the exception!")

with suppress_exceptions(IOError):
    1/0

# The second one will let the exception through
```

Comment: This would be messy, but I think its the only way to achieve what I need (instance level "decorator")

Answer (score 3):

Decorator would be perfect for this:

```
def protected_call(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            pass
    return wrapper
```

Sample usage:

```
@protected_call
def foo():
    raise Exception()

# nothing is being raised
foo()
```

Comment: the decorator works as if he'd written foo = protected_call(foo)

Comment: I want to be able to define this on the instance... there are going to be cases where other clients are going to want to call foo() and see the exception.  I will try and explain above...

Comment: Then your approach is probably better. With decorator you would have to do: `protected_foo = protected_call(foo); protected_foo()` so this is more code actually. Alternatively you can use metaclasses to add protected version of every method automatically. This could work by adding `protected_XXX` method for every method in given class.

Comment: I can show you an example with metaclasses if you think it'd be viable.

Comment: I was hoping to somehow leverage annotations at an instance level.. if its not possible I might just leave what I have.

Comment: This answer doesn't do what I need it to do, it does the same exact thing that I do but with an annotation.

Comment: True, after you clarified your question, my answer isn't really helpful in you case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a decorator

```
def protected_call(func):
    def inner(*args, **kw):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kw)
    except:
            pass
    return inner

class Test():

    @protected_call
    def throws_exception(self):
        print 1/0

    @protected_call
    def no_exception(self):
        print 4

    def sometimes_need_exception(self):
        print 5
    protected_sometimes_need_exception = protected_call(sometimes_need_exception)

    def stop(self):
        self.throws_exception()
    self.no_exception()
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this when I call it, because there will be cases where people will need to know that this threw an exception.    I am guessing I am just going to have to wrap this in another call.  See above i added an additional section.

Comment: @Nix, I added an example where the decorated method is bound to a different name

Comment: So am i stuck wrapping all calls ?

Comment: Yes, there is no `On Error Resume Next` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

At least logging exceptions seems to be a useful feature here or how else will you have control over unexpected errors...?

Comment: I own a thread, I am asking to shut it down, if it doesn't do it gracefuly I dont really care (to an extent, I care about mem leaks), bc I am going to be reinitializing everything.